# Is a server required for push notifications?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Just to start I, I want to say I have read the this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

After reading it, had a few questions about push notifications... my main questions is, is a server required.

I have made an app that has informational content for my business... however every week/month or whenever I choose, I want to be able to push a message to all the user who have downloaded my app (every device would receive the same message).

Preferably, the way I would want to create and send the notifications... is through a separate  app that I, the developer only has.

Now back to my question, would I need to get a server to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use a framework called Parse that let's us send broadcast pushes to all users.  You don't need to maintain a server (they do it for you).  It's free for under 5 million queries a month.

Comment: Can you link me to more information about Parse, I've had trouble finding the correct thing. Is it a framework inside Xcode?

Comment: I'm about a decade too late, but the documentation appears to be [here](https://docs.parseplatform.org/)

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of free Push Notification servers - for example [QuickBlox](http://quickblox.com)
You don't need any server code, QuickBlox already wrote all for you.

Just look at [Push Notifications iOS sample](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-ios) - This sample enables you to send notifications and alerts to users at any time through an API or easy-to-use admin panel.
Just download it, move some code from it to your app - and enjoy it.

Answer (score 0):

No you dont need a server, you can simply create your own application that connects to the apple push notification server but you have to ensure you use the required develop/publish certificate for the ssl connection, you can see that on the tutorial you read in the "Making a PEM file" secction. He is connecting directly from his mac to the servers, it fails without the certificate but it doesnt with it.

See here:

> As I’ve mentioned a few times before, you need to set up a server that
>   sends the push notifications to your app. For this first test, we’re
>   not going to set up a server just yet. Instead, I’ll give you a very
>   simple PHP script that sets up a connection to APNS and sends a push
>   notification to a device token that you specify. You can run this
>   straight from your Mac.

You can make your program set up a connection like that.